# How do I override the MuiCheckbox icon defaultProp in theme.ts?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to override the icon default prop for Mui checkbox (as described [here](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#default-props)), using an override snippet from [the docs](https://mui.com/components/checkboxes/#customization):

```
const BpIcon = styled('span')(({ theme }) => ({
  borderRadius: 3,
  width: 16,
  height: 16,
  ...
}));

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiCheckbox: {
      defaultProps: {
        icon: <BpIcon />,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

but getting the following error:

```
./src/theme.ts
Error: error: Expression expected
  
   |
81 |         icon: <BpIcon />,
   |                       ^
```

Also tried passing `icon: BpIcon` and see:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Call Stack
Module.default
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends.js (3:43)
deepmerge
node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/deepmerge.js (8:33)
eval
node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/deepmerge.js (19:0)
```

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You could try `icon: BpIcon`

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I tried that and got a different error -- edited post to reflect :)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the icon only works when renaming your `theme.ts` file to `theme.tsx` after that you can use the following code:

```
    const theme = createTheme({
        components: {
            // Name of the component
            MuiCheckbox: {
                defaultProps: {
                    icon: <BpIcon />,
                },
            },
        }
    });
```